# Run heavy task programmed in Rust that is called from Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rust

I am working on an app and I use a Rust api I wrote. I am struggling with the threads/coroutines.
I have the following code to run

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_..._MainActivity_init (env: JNIEnv, _: JObject) {
    error!("pks8: {:?}", Path::new("PA").exists());
    if !Path::new("PASSWORD.txt").exists() {
        error!("in ");
        File::create("PASSWORD.txt").expect("Unable to create meta.json file");

        // Generate key
        let rng = rand::SystemRandom::new();
        let pkcs8_bytes = signature::Ed25519KeyPair::generate_pkcs8(&rng).unwrap();
        error!("next");
}
```

Since I thought it would be a heavy task I decided to run it in a thread so I did the following

```kotlin
val init_rust = Thread {
     if (init()) {
        sleep(1000)
        runOnUiThread() {
            amountAv.text = get_amount()
        }
     } else {
        println("Init err")
     }
}

init_rust.start()
```

However this throws the following error

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 11068 (Thread-3), pid 11009 (le....)
```

For what I understood this means that a task is overloading the UI thread, what I don't really understand since isn't the thread supposed to run outside of it ?

So I created a Rust thread in my function and decided to run the body of the function inside it.

```rust
thread::spawn(move || {
 ... body of the function
}).join();
```

This seems to have solved the problem about running on the main thread but then it does not run until the end, the code stops at the level error!("in"), so I guess the thread is killed.

Since running it in a Thread was not working I tried to use coroutines, I did the following:

```kotlin
launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    init_rust()
}

private suspend fun init_rust(amountAv: TextView) {
        if (init()) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Send failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            sleep(1000)
            runOnUiThread() {
                amountAv.text = get_amount()
            }
        } else {
            println("Init err")
        }
    }
```

I also tried with `Default.IO` but it is giving me the same result than using threads.
I added the followinf permissions to the manifest:

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Does anyone has an idea on how I could fix it ?

Edit 1: I found out that if I used the following code:

```rust
 let x = thread::spawn(move || { 
   ...
 });
 let result = x.join();
 println!("Result {:?}", result.unwrap());
```

I get the error:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 21459 (DefaultDispatch), pid 21386 (le. ...)
```

Comment: Note that it is useless to spawn a thread and immediately `join` it: this has the effect of blocking the current thread until the other one completes, so you might as well do the computation directly in the current thread.

Comment: IIC what you want, you will need to change your API so that is asynchronous: have a function that starts the computation and returns a handle, then have Kotlin poll the handle to check if the computation has completed or have some kind of callback mechanism to enable Rust to notify the Kotlin code when it completes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused about the handle, I thought by having my method returning a value, it would notify Kotlin that it was done.

Comment: Yes but that's the point: your method must return _before_ the value has finished computing, otherwise you are blocking the Kotlin thread for the duration of the computation → hence the need for a handle or a callback that will allow the Kotlin thread to get the result later once the computing thread has finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time, it is finally working